# Docker container entry points complain "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I've been stumped trying to run Nextcloud via docker for the past few weeks. I've tried using ownyourbits/nextcloudpi, nextcloud, and the example docker-compose scripts provided by the Nextcloud team, but they will all complain about some file being unexecutable. However, I do have other containers successfully running.

Since this happens with multiple containers, I think it must be a problem with my system. If I exec into the container, I'm able to use apt to reinstall the affected files and get things working. However, this will be undone when new containers are pulled.

Trying to example the files will give errors like these: `objdump: /usr/bin/jq: file format not recognized`. The affected programs work fine on my docker host.

It almost appears that binaries are being corrupted as they're being pulled from dockerhub... is this possible? What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 19.10 x86_64:

```bsh
chase@chase-server:~$ uname -a
Linux chase-server 5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Sorry about that, added to the bottom of the OP

Comment: I've tried multiple images, but the latest I'm having trouble with is `ownyourbits/nextcloudpi`. I create the container with `docker create -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -v ncdata:/data --name nextcloudpi ownyourbits/nextcloudpi nextcloud.chaselau.me`. using file on jq reads: `/usr/bin/jq: data`

Comment: That's definately wrong - https://pastebin.com/H3eQw61v... can you try removing the image and re-acquiring it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that quite a few times. Do you know of any way docker would link things like jq from a container with the host system? I can't think of a reason why the library would be pulled down wrong...

Comment: Did you follow the steps I took in the pastebin dump? Docker should be pretty good a ensuring integrity of retrieved images, however it may be possible that your local storage is falling... have you had any other problems?

Comment: Thanks for helping troubleshoot Attie... unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. ```root@e5b997f1316e:/# file /usr/bin/jq 
file: bad magic in `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc' (No such file or directory)
/usr/bin/jq: data
``` is what I get after running your commands. No difference. My understanding of Docker is that the container is supposed to be completely separate from the host, but it appears not to be. Here's the docker packages I have installed on my host: https://pastebin.com/1CQrLqGb

Comment: Please could you share the output of `docker system info`? Could you try installing [`docker-ce`](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) instead of `docker.io`? Something is very wrong with your system...

Comment: Here's my `docker system info`: https://pastebin.com/gd46bw9e

I had just switched from docker-ce to docker.io in an attempt to solve this problem. Perhaps next I'll try podman. I'm beginning to think this is one of the unfortunate problems where a reinstall is the solution!

Comment: Please add the output of `docker image inspect ownyourbits/nextcloudpi`. Also, is there a reason to use `ownyourbits/nextcloudpi` instead of the `nextcloud` image?

Comment: Here's the paste of `docker image inspect ownyourbits/nextcloudpi`: https://pastebin.com/MgcKubbG

In this case I'm just trying anything. Other Nextcloud-based images have the same problems. I do like Nextcloudpi though because it offers a great all-in-one package :)